# Square Payment Processing Error: HTTP Response Not OK | Using Connect .net API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, square

Im using asp.net API from Connect Square to generate nonce and create a payment. My payment form is loading correctly generating a nonce but not creating paymentrequest. Here is the error response

```
HTTP Response Not OKSquare.Exceptions.ApiException: HTTP Response Not OK at
 Square.Utilities.ApiHelper.RunTaskSynchronously(Task t) at
 Square.Apis.PaymentsApi.CreatePayment(CreatePaymentRequest body) at
 sqRazorSample.Pages.ProcessPaymentModel.OnPost() in 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\csharp_payment\Pages\ProcessPayment.cshtml.cs:line 60
```

Here is the code at line 60.. payment Creation

```
 public void OnPost()
    {
        string nonce = Request.Form["nonce"];
        // IPaymentsApi paymentsApi = new PaymentsApi(this.BasePath);
        // paymentsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = this.AccessToken;
        IPaymentsApi PaymentsApi = client.PaymentsApi;

        string uuid = NewIdempotencyKey(); //NewIdempotencyKey();
        Money amount = new Money(100, "USD");

        CreatePaymentRequest createPaymentRequest = new CreatePaymentRequest(amountMoney: amount, idempotencyKey: uuid, sourceId: nonce);
        try
        {
            var response = PaymentsApi.CreatePayment(createPaymentRequest); \\This is giving error
            this.ResultMessage = "Payment complete! " + response;
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            this.ResultMessage = e.Message + e;
        }
    }
```

Working in Sandbox environment and localhost. Anyhelp would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My account was in GPB and currency set here was in USD. exception is not printing error details. so we have to print it in an object